# How does Laravel's migration up and down method work?

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration

In this code the table is created in the up method and deleted in the down() method. When I run the migration, the table is created but not deleted. In what way can I trigger the down method, so that I get a better understanding on how the two methods work?

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateFlightsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('flights', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('airline');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('flights');
    }
}
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#rolling-back-migrations

Comment: You have any error in your first trying migration ?

Comment: I copied the code from the documentation. I ran the code the table is getting created.

Comment: The `down` method exists to run when the migration is rolled back, e.g: `php artisan migrate:rollback` will delete the table `flights`. You are expected to write code to reverse what was done in `up`, e.g: if `up` adds a new column; `down` deletes it. The down method only runs when you roll back the migration.

Comment: Also there is create method to create a new table but  there is the table method to update existing tables. How to use those? I mean create method will go in one class and when I want to edit the existing table should I create a new class and use the table method?

Comment: The `up` method can contain whatever you like; you can create tables, update tables, delete tables, do data transformation: the `up` method is just like any other class method, it has no constraints. You should read the [migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations) documentation to understand the functionality available to you; it'll explain better than I can in this comment.

Comment: @Deeven Try reading the documentation. It’s explained there: https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### In your example:

`php artisan migrate` will run your **up()** method.

`php artisan migrate:rollback` will run your **down()** method.

Read up on the excellent docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations#migration-structure

Answer (score 7):

You sohuld add `dropIfExists` instead of `drop`

and if you wanna just drop the specific migration file you should write your code in command like this:

```
php artisan migrate:rollback --path=\database\migrations\flights.php
```

Comment: You probably want to run `--path=/\database/\migrations/\flights.php` instead of `--path=\database\migrations\flights.php` because the example above executes `databasemigrationsflights.php`.

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel, We have multiple migration options available that will be used to migrate the table or roll back the table using the `up()` and `down()` methods.

The `up()` method is mainly used to perform certain operations on tables like `creating tables`, `adding new fields`, `updating tables`, etc...

While the `down()` method is used to rollback the migration like `delete tables`, `delete columns from table`, etc...

You can create a new migration by using the following command

`php artisan make migration create_customers_table`

Here `customers` is a table name.

Now We have 2 methods available that will help you to migrate or rollback the data.

1. `up()`: `php artisan migrate`
2. `down()`:  `php artisan migrate:rollback`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('flights');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, up() is for creating tables or altering tables in the database, and down() is for reverting those changes.
Note: both of these methods create your own logic that how you want to go about making changes.

calling these methods:

1. **up()** `php artisan migrate`
2. **down()** `php artisan migrate:rollback`